# Xpages - compute properties for dominoDocument does not work as expected

Tags: xpages

on an XPage I have defined a dominoDocument datasource as followed:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:bundle src="/datasources.properties" var="datasources" />
        <xp:bundle src="/environment.properties" var="env"></xp:bundle>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument formName="fa_Attachment" var="attachDoc">
            <xp:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:return env["srv_notesname"] + "!!" + utilityBean.getFilePath() + "//" + datasources["db_inbox_filepath"]}]]></xp:this.databaseName>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
```

in environment.properties i have listed key/value pair:

```
# ENVIRONMENT SETTINGS REFERENCES
#
srv_notesname=Server01/Server/ACME
```

similar for datasource.properties:

```
# DB Inbox
db_inbox_filepath=inbox.nsf
```

when I load the XPage I get the message:

> com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing
>   JavaScript computed expression Error while executing JavaScript
>   computed expression Script interpreter error, line=1, col=8:
>   [ReferenceError] 'env' not found

I would have expect that I could make the data binding a bit dynamic, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Datasources that are children of the `xp:view` element need to have their properties generated *before beforePageLoad*. "Print" statements will allow you to confirm that, as I did for my session a few years ago "Marty, You're Just Not Thinking Fourth Dimensionally" (probably still available as a webinar on the TLCC website).

Making it a child of a Panel will allow you to pick up things set in `beforePageLoad`.

Datasources can't be changed during the life of a page unless scoped to `request`. So you can use `${javascript:...}` instead of `#{javascript:...}`

Comment: hi Paul, basically you are saying that those bundle-resources are not available for the datasources? When I define the datasource on a custom control and place that on the xpage then the budnles seems to be available.

Comment: I'm not sure if they're loaded in the order they display on the XPage. So the order of `resources` and `datasource` may be handled differently, I don't know. Printing `requestScope.keySet()` would tell you if the resources have been added loaded and added to the requestScope.Moving the datasource to a Panel would definitely ensure it's loaded later than resources

Comment: I have changed my code now that the dominodocument is set as datacontext for the (first) panel that contains all other design elements and then I no longer have problem calculating the property for the database. thanks for helping me :-)

Comment: Understand datacontexts get recomputed multiple times for every refresh. Paul Withers blogged about that... not good for your performance!

Comment: It sounds like it's still an `xp:this.data` rather than `xp:this.dataContext`, so fine. It depends where the dataContext is located (Panel's recompute less), what's put there and whether it's computed on page load or computed dynamically. If a dataContext is for example getting a sessionScope variable, yes it will recompute multiple times, but it's a single call, so aggregate performance is still minimal. If a dataContext is trawling a view doing @DbLookups to another server to get associated data and building an Array of objects, then aggregate will be very bad.

Comment: Performance of writing, deploying, running, supporting a single basic dataContext is very good. Performance of learning Java, learning how to implement it in XPages, learning how to code a pageController with lazy-loading, reference it on the XPage, coding that, deploying it and supporting it and so avoid writing it in a dataContext is very bad. I firmly believe performance is not just about speed of code, but also speed of functional delivery to customer and speed / quality of supportability. It's a balancing act :-)